# Java no me inicializa una variable como le indiqué en mi constructor

Tags: java, poo, constructor, java-7

Estaba creando una clase la cual te permite pedir datos al usuario usando `Scanner`, y lo importe en otro codigo para probar si realmente funcionaba pero cuando lo compilo usando `javac` no pasa nada pero cuando ejecuto el codigo con java en el [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) me da el error:

> Exception in thread “main” NullPointerException at entrada.usuario.Wix.Entrada1(Wix.java:19) at Pr.main(Pr.java:12)

```
package entrada.usuario;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Wix {

    Scanner entrada;

    public void Wix() {


        entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    
    }

    public void Entrada1() {
        String entrada_string = entrada.nextLine();
    }

    public void Entrada2() {
        String entrada_string_cort = entrada.next();
    }



}
```

Y este es el codigo donde lo importe:

```
import entrada.usuario.Wix;


public class Pr {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Wix entrada = new Wix();

        System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre aqui: ");

        entrada.Entrada1();


    }
}
```

Comment: porque entrada no la has definido, te recomiendo poner un constructor y tu mensaje de error completo en la pregunta

Comment: Listo ya lo edite, para que puedan ayudarme con mas detalle

Comment: sigue sin tener un constructor y sin verse tu mensaje de error que te da, recuerda que no todos leen el título al abrir la publicación

Comment: Ah que te refieres con el constructor, dices el constructor de la clase?

Comment: sí, justo lo que no pusiste ;)

Comment: **public void Wix() {


        entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    
    }** Pero aqui esta el constructor podrias ser mas explicito porque la verdad aqui esta el constructor con todo lo correspondiente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si amigo tenes toda la razon, cuando cree el metodo constructor puse: `public void Wix() { entrada = new Scanner(System.in); }` y esto esta mal ya que jamas se debe poner void ya que java lo detecta como un metodo get y no como un metodo constructor, lo cual provoca que me de error ya que no encuentra el metodo constructor.

Muchisimas gracias, un abrazo.